# Framer-motion typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

How to combine MotionType and my custom type to pass it to component.
Code:

```
type MotionDivProps = HTMLMotionProps<"div"> & MyCustomProps;
export const MyComponent: React.FC<MotionDivProps> = ({
  myprop,
  className,
  ...props
}): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <motion.div
      {...props}
      className={`${className}`}
      onMouseEnter={() => someFunc(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => someFunc(false)}
    ></motion.div>)}
```

This type isn't assignable.Thanks for advises.